# notepad++ regex search and replace

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am trying to get from this:

```
1200        PORTAL  oracle  29489   17:57   48 username cell single block physical read 2
```

to this:

```
EXEC SYS.KILLSID (1200,29489,2)
```

Comment: also 1st number (1200) can be any number from 1 to 4 digits long. some thing with second number (29489) could be 4 to 5 digits long and last number (2) is always 1 digit long.

Answer (score 1):

```
find ^(\d{1,4}) [^\d]\*(\d{4,5}) .*(\d)$
replace EXEC SYS.KILLSID (\1,\2,\3)
```

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\d{1,4})\D+(\d{4,5}).+(\d)$`
- Replace with: `EXEC SYS.KILLSID \($1,$2,$3\)`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
  (\d{1,4}) : group 1, 1 to 4 digits
  \D+       : 1 or more non digits
  (\d{4,5}) : group 2, 4 or 5 digits
  .+        : 1 or more any character but newline
  (\d)      : group 3, 1 digit
$           : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
EXEC SYS.KILLSID    : literally
\(                  : open parenthesis, in Npp, it has to be escaped
  $1                : content of group 1
  ,                 : a comma
  $2                : content of group 2
  ,                 : a comma
  $3                : content of group 3
\(                  : close parenthesis, in Npp, it has to be escaped
```

**Result for given example:**

```
EXEC SYS.KILLSID (1200,29489,2)
```